# Swift scaleAspectFill only width

Tags: ios, swift

I have got a `UIImageView` in Swift

```
let background_image: UIImageView = {
    let v = UIImageView()
    v.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "basketball")
    v.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()
```

What i want to do here is to have the image fill the background without getting smaller or bigger.
Imagine this image is the background
[image]

What I want to do is to get the **100x100 px** of this image and show only that. Just like in this [image.](https://dribbble.com/shots/1675014-Social-iPhone-App/attachments/264620)

Comment: Are you want to crop image 100*100 from center?

Comment: @Nirmalsinh no i want to show the 100*100 px from center only

Comment: v.contentMode = .center

Comment: @JaydeepVyas now image takes the whole `view`

Comment: set v.clipsToBounds = true and run the code

Comment: @JaydeepVyas that's what i'm talking about!

Comment: Small thing but `background_image` is not named correctly. It is not an image it is an image view. It contains an image. Also, snake case? Should be `backgroundImageView`.

Comment: @Fogmeister thanks for the correction!

Comment: @JaydeepVyas will ye deign to answer this question thus our children will also benefit?

Comment: @sakoaskoaso no worries. When you're writing in a different programming language you should take everything that comes with it. Formatting and naming practises included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For crop the image from center  you have to set the content mode to center and allow image to clips to bound which prevent image view size

```
imageView.contentMode = .center /* take center part of image*/
imageView. clipsToBounds = true /* prevent image view size*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set two properties of UIImageView.

**Programmatically:**

```
imgView.contentMode = .center
imgView.clipsToBounds = true
```

**If you are using Storyboard, then you can set directly:**

[image]

Comment: its just duplication

Comment: If you are creating image using Programmatically, then go with first one. Otherwise you can directly set property from storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

set the contentmodel as this

```
v.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Comment: This resizes width and height.If you read the question carefully which i'm sure you did,i said `to have the image fill the background without getting smaller or bigger`